# How can one migrate questions for StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

How are questions from SO imported on Magento SE ?

I first thought it was only old questions when Magento SE was released but this one is from April 21st: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112037/migration-from-magento-1-to-magento-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal users only see some predefined migration paths.

For Magento.SE there is only one, to Meta.Magento.SE

[image]

For StackOverflow it looks like this:

[image]

To migrate posts to different sites, you have to flag them because only moderators can do that.

Answer (score 2):

When closing a question you can specify that the question belongs to an other website in the SE network.
If the question gets closed with that specified reason it gets migrated.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a special privilege to do so ? Because I don't see the "belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network" option when I close a question

Comment: You don't see one under the "off topic" reason?

Comment: Nope that's all I see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xFMX8.png

Comment: Maybe it's only for moderators? I'm not sure.

Comment: Well thanks for that, I guess I need to step up my game again to access it ^^